# How to double quote escape the embedded java in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to make an feature that could make my image button disappear when user don't have the Permission.

```
<input type="image"
src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/pencil.png"
onClick="document.sentToBack.submit()" />
```

Above one is the original code that I'm trying to make it display conditionally.

```
<% 
    if(DisplayBtn == true) { 
        out.println("<input type=\"image\""
        + " src=\"/img/pencil.png\""
        + " onClick=\"document.sentToBack.submit()\" />");
    }
%>
```

This one is workable, but won't display my image properly because that path isn't correct. And if I put my embedded java back into above code, it will tell me that I'm not properly double-quoted that string.

Can anyone tell me how to escape that embedded java and make it works as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change as follows:

```
<% 
    if(DisplayBtn == true) { 
%>
        <input type="image" src="/img/pencil.png" onClick="document.sentToBack.submit()" />
<% 
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace double quote with single quote

```
<% 
    if(DisplayBtn == true) { 
        out.println("<input type='image'"
        + " src='img/pencil.png'"
        + " onClick='document.sentToBack.submit()' />");
    }
%>
```

Comment: nope, this one doesn't work if I add that embedded Java back into it.